How to explain discrepancies between the way LAME and FFmpeg encode with low CBR MP3 files?
I am trying to find the matching FFmpeg options that would produce the equal result when using lame. We are using CBR mostly so the transition seems to be straightforward.
LAME: -b XXX --cbr -m j -q 2 -t
ffmpeg: -codec:a libmp3lame -b:a XXXk  -compression_level 2

Where XXX denotes the bitrates in this range (64, 128, 192, 256, 320)
I was testing this conversion against a set of miscellaneous audio files with different sample rates (44100, 48000, 96000, 176400, 192000). The output results were a match for all CBR rates but 64.
Here is a quick summary.
inp freq   lame   ffmpeg
44100   -> 24000, 44100
48000   -> 24000, 48000
88200   -> 24000, 48000
96000   -> 24000, 48000
176400  -> 24000, 48000
192000  -> 24000, 48000

In all cases LAME resampled to 24000, and FFmpeg did not follow.
Here in this wiki article it says:

CBR bitrates below 104 kbps, the input is resampled to 32000, 24000,
22050, 16000, 12000, 11025, or 8000, depending on the target quality
level or bitrate.

But it looks like FFmpeg does not follow this rule? Am I missing something?

In FFmpeg the audio sample rate is determined by the argument -ar. For example, add -ar 24000 for 24000 samples per second. I don't think there is an option for FFmpeg to automatically select the sample rate by given bitrate.

I had an impression that libmp3lame library decides how to resample.
